# SharePoint 2010 Server + Win 7 64-bit Required for SharePoint Development?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have been looking for solutions to developing a SharePoint Workflow project, but everything I have found points to the requirement to have SharePoint 2010 server and Windows 7 64bit installed on the development PC.  It seems like a very awkward approach in the first place, but is there any way around this?  I am not in the position to have Windows 7 64-bit on my PC less SharePoint Server 2010.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small project you will probably be fine with the free Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en .  It will run on many more OS's than Win7x64.

edit: I was mistaken; SF 2010 only runs on Server 2008/R2... a big and unwelcome change from WSS 2007.

edit again: Through some command-line drudgery, Microsoft says you can get SF 2010 working (for development, not production) on Vista, Win 7, and Server 2008.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx  However, only the 64-bit operating systems are supported.

Comment: WSSv3 also wasn't supported on anything else than Windows 2003/2008 Server, it was just possible to "hack" it into Vista and potentially XP Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual Machine if your Physical Machine is not compatible, More on Developing for Sharepoint on VM or Physical Machine here sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51741/use-of-virtual-machines-for-sharepoint-development